# Verificar que mail se haya enviado correctamente usando JAVA mail

Tags: android, app

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Texto = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mensaje);
    Enviar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enviar);

    Enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


            Properties propiedades = new Properties();

            propiedades.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.googlemail.com");
            propiedades.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port","465");
            propiedades.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            propiedades.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
            propiedades.put("mail.smtp.port","465");

            try{

                session = Session.getDefaultInstance(propiedades, new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Correo,Contrasena);
                    }
                });

             if (session!=null)
                {
                    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Correo));
                    message.setSubject("Primera Prueba JAVA Mail");
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("lepanier.pruebas.ventas@gmail.com"));
                    message.setContent(Texto.getText().toString(),"text/html; charset=utf-8");

                    Transport.send(message);


                }



            }



            catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    });
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que estás usando para enviar el correo? Dependiendo de la función, podría devolver verdadero cuando se envía el correo o falso si hubo algún error, aunque, también podría lanzar una excepción y, si es el caso, deberías usar try-catch.

Comment: El try-catch que tengo es por si falla el inicio de sesión, yo necesito verificar que el correo efectivamente de envio. Gracias!

Comment: Separa la logica en dos bloques `try..catch` . Además es una mala practica poner `catch (Exception e)`. Captura sólo la excepción específica, al menos mientras estas desarrollando la app. De otra manera se hace mas dificil detectar otros posibles errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         if (session!=null)
            {
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Correo));
                message.setSubject("Primera Prueba JAVA Mail");
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("lepanier.pruebas.ventas@gmail.com"));
                message.setContent(Texto.getText().toString(),"text/html; charset=utf-8");
                try {
                    Transport.send(message);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    /* El correo no se envió */
                }
            }
```

Por supuesto, esto no te va a garantizar que llegue a bandeja de entrada, porque eso depende de factores externos, pero al menos puedes estar seguro de que el correo sí se envió.

Comment: Perfecto!!!!! Justo estaba pensando en algo asi...Gracias!! lo hare asi!

Comment: @JesusRomeroG recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como "Aceptada", puedes hacer el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).